# Deploying RapidClipse X to desktop application

Tags: configuration, rapidclipse

I'm trying to find out what the possibilities are within RapidClipse X to build crossplatform desktop applications running both on Windows and MacOS (fat client). However, in the QuickLaunch window, there is only 'Start Servlet' and 'Build Web App (.war)', not what the documentation says ('Build Desktop Application' (amongst others)). Am I missing something in the setup of my RapidClipse environment ?

Answer (score 0):

currently RapidClipse X has no crossplatform desktop application deployment. I am assuming that you were looking at the RapidClipse 4 documentation. [Here is a link to the german RapidClipse X documentation.](https://rapidclipse.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RCXDOCDE/overview) The english documentation will be up very soon.